# if nested CLIPS

Tags: if-statement, clips

what is the correct syntax for nested if CLIPS ?

```
(defrule determina-si-tiene-gripe ""
?A <- (enfermedad (Gripe nose) (compostura))
=>
(if (si-o-no-p "Tiene Fiebre(si/no)? ")
 (if (si-o-no-p "Tiene dolores en el cuerpo(si/no)? ")
     if (si-o-no-p "Tiene dolor de garganta(si/no)? ")
      then (modify ?A (Gripe si)(compostura "El paciente tiene un Resfrio"))
    else (modify ?A (Gripe no)))
 else (modify ?A (Gripe no)))
else (modify ?A (Gripe no))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested if-the-else is just another action inside then or else branch, as stated in the [doc](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~sylee/courses/clips/bpg/node12.6.2.html):

> Any number of allowable actions may be used inside of the then or else portion, including another if...then...else structure.

So it should be something like

```
(if (si-o-no-p "Tiene Fiebre(si/no)? ")
  then
  (if (si-o-no-p "Tiene dolores en el cuerpo(si/no)? ")
    then
    (if (si-o-no-p "Tiene dolor de garganta(si/no)? ")
      then
      (modify ?A (Gripe si)(compostura "El paciente tiene un Resfrio"))
      else (modify ?A (Gripe no)))
    else (modify ?A (Gripe no)))
  else (modify ?A (Gripe no))))
```

However it seems that your example does not require nested if's, all that is needed is one if with several conditions:

```
(if (and (si-o-no-p "Tiene Fiebre(si/no)? ")
         (si-o-no-p "Tiene dolores en el cuerpo(si/no)? ")
         (si-o-no-p "Tiene dolor de garganta(si/no)? "))
  then
  (modify ?A (Gripe si)(compostura "El paciente tiene un Resfrio"))
  else (modify ?A (Gripe no)))
```

(there seems to be user input involved, but this might work anyway)